# Library to SDK in Android

Tags: java, android, build, sdk

I've been searching for info about it on the internet but I haven't found anything.

The point is that I want to transform my library for android, which I'm using for advertising, into an sdk to make it available for other developers.

My library is mainly an extension of the Application class and I don't know if this should be the way an sdk is made, mainly because it seems weird to me that a .jar extends the Application class.

So, I'm asking for some advices/tips/guidelines or whatever you could tell me in order to build an sdk.

Comment: Are you using any resources (like layout xml, strings xml, drawables, etc) in your library? Also, are you willing to send source code to the developers using it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using resources (an activity for displaying the ad) and I'm not willing to send the source, only to distribute the sdk.

Comment: If you use resources, you can't use a standard jar. Your options would be .apklib or .aar EXCEPT that .apklib distributes the resources in plaintext. If that's not acceptable, look into .aar, which is used by the new Android Studio build system. I don't have a concrete answer for you, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: ok, thank you Matt. So if I'm getting rid of these resources, can I make a .jar? I can inflate a View with the adwall instead of using an activity, for example. I'm not very comfortable with using alternative methods like the ones you describe.

Comment: If your res/, assets/, raw/, drawable/, etc. directories are empty, you're just compiling java files -- you can compile those java files into class files and include them in a jar (in fact, the ide does it for you) and you should be able to pass that around. Are you using Eclipse?